# Angular JS ng-model passing to a function undefined object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ContactUsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Contact Us</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="login-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="SU_Name" class="sr-only">Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" ng-model="contactus.Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="SU_Email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Email" ng-model="contactus.Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">Message</label>
                <textarea rows="5" cols="50" ng-model-="contactus.Message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message" ></textarea>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="SendEmail(contactus)">Submit</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when calling SendEmail(contactus) and alert in that function of contactus.Message for example i get undefined object ?

Answer (score 1):

> contactus.Message for example i get undefined object ?

Because for message field you don't even provide ngModel attribute. Take a closer look: you have `ng-model-` attribute which is not the same as `ng-model`.

So the typo led to this confusion.